# MessagingException nested IOException while connection to gmail imap in JBoss

Tags: linux, sockets, jboss, jakarta-mail, serversocket

Getting the following exception while trying to connect to the store.

```
2:56:26,020 ERROR [STDERR] javax.mail.MessagingException;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.invient.tickets.emailprocessor.EmailProcessorUtil.connect(Unknown Source)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.invient.tickets.emailprocessor.EmailProcessorThread.connect(Unknown Source)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.invient.tickets.emailprocessor.EmailProcessorThread.run(Unknown Source)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.io.IOException
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.read0(ResponseInputStream.java:99)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:67)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:48)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:122)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:230)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
12:56:26,021 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
12:56:26,022 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
12:56:26,022 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 5 more
```

The following is my Properties list

```
prop.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");
prop.put("mail.imap.user", "abc");
prop.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
prop.put("mail.debug", "false");
prop.put("mail.imap.port", "993") ;
prop.put("mail.debug.quote", "false") ;        
prop.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap") ;
```

When I do the following

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(prop);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "userName", "passwd");
```

I get the above exception. 
When I tried the same code with a standalore program, it worked fine. I was able to connect. But when I put the code in to my JBoss, it throws the exception.

When I went into the source of mail.jar where it throwed exception, I could see that when it tries to read from the Socket it throws the exception.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Normally the exception will include a "message", which seems to be missing from your output.  The message includes more detail about why you got that exception.  When you tried with a standalone program, was the program running on the same machine as your JBoss server?  The JavaMail FAQ has more [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: @BillShannon The Exception had only those details, no message was shown and yes the JBoss is running in the same machine as that of the standalone program. Actually now I found the solution to the problem. I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following properties the connect works. Can anybody explain what was the problem with the earlier setup?

```
prop.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");
prop.put("mail.imap.user", "abc");
prop.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
prop.put("mail.debug", "true");
prop.put("mail.imap.port", "993") ;
prop.put("mail.debug.quote", "false") ;        
prop.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps") ;
prop.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
prop.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Comment: You absolutely [should not need those socketFactory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) unless you're using a **very** old version of JavaMail.  What version are you using?  Note also that since you're using the "imaps" protocol, **all** of those mail.imap.* properties are being ignored.  And since you're passing the host name, user name, and password into the connect call, you never needed to set them in properties.  With a not-old version of JavaMail, setting mail.imap.ssl.enable is the same as using the "imaps" protocol.

Comment: I'm currently using javamail 1.4.2. Are socketFactory properties needed in this version?

Comment: No, built-in SSL support was added in 1.3.2 and the mail.*.ssl.enable properties were added in 1.4.2, released over 6 years ago.  The web is still full of obsolete example code that people copy.